# PHP7 mysqli is missing

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I'm using windows 10, Apache2.4, PHP 7.4.5

//in httpd.conf

...
PHPIniDir "E:/PHP"

LoadModule php7_module "E:/PHP/php7apache2_4.dll"

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html .php

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

// and in php.ini

...
On windows:

extension_dir = "E:/PHP/ext"

...
extension=mysqli

...

Restarting apache or my computer didn't work. 
phpinfo() shows php tables well, but mysqli isn't there but only the text "mysqli" is in PHP Credits.
php_mysqli.dll file is already there ("E:/PHP/ext") and I'm sure the file will be no problem.
Is there any missing I missed to check, please?

Comment: what php ini is shown in phpinfo?

Comment: Configuration : apache2handler, Apache Environment, HTTP Headers Information, bcmath, calendar, Core, ctype, date, dom, filter, hash, iconv, json, libxml, mysqlnd, pcre, PDO, Phar, readline, Reflection, session, SimpleXML, SPL, standard,

Comment: oh sry I'm writing more

Comment: which **path to php.ini**  is shown in phpinfo?

Comment: if you mean where is php.ini, It is in E:/php